# copy list in python

Tags: python, list, memory, multidimensional-array

As I am trying to make a copy of a list and do some stuff with the copy of the list. Somehow my original list is modified as well. I already looked at different memory allocatinos and different ways of assigning the lists. So far no luck... Any ideas?

```
    row = 0
    column = 0
    table1 = copy.copy(table[:])

    temptable = []
    temptable = table[:]

    print id(table)
    print table
    print id(table1)
    print table1
    print id(temptable)
    print temptable

    for i in temptable:
        for j in i:
            if type(j) == str:
                temptable[row][column] = 0
            column = column + 1
        column = 0
        row = row + 1
    result=[]   

    for column in zip(*temptable):
        try:
                result.append(sum(map(int,column)))
            except ValueError:
                result.append(0)


    print table
    print table1
    print temptable
```

/#### Results

```
163783148
[[0, 'ZZZ', 'XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA', 0, 0], ['BBB', 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], ['CCC', 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['DDD', 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['EEE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

163669036
[[0, 'ZZZ', 'XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA', 0, 0], ['BBB', 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], ['CCC', 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['DDD', 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['EEE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

163783468
[[0, 'ZZZ', 'XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA', 0, 0], ['BBB', 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], ['CCC', 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['DDD', 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], ['EEE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], [0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], [0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], [0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 26, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Have you tried `copy.deepcopy()`?

Answer (score 12):

Your original list contains inner lists:

```
[[0, 'ZZZ', 'XXX', 'YYY', 'AAA', 0, 0], 
 ['BBB', 1, 1, 0, 26, 28, 0], ...
]
```

The inner list are actually stored as references, i.e.:

```
[ location-of-list-0, 
  location-of-list-1, ...
]
```

When you copied the list, you actually copied a list of references to the same lists stored in your original list. This is called shallow copy, as it copies references rather than contents.

Use [deep copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) to create a totally separate list.

## Illustrations

### Original List

[image]

### Shallow copy

[image]

### Deep copy

[image]

Comment: +1 for the illustrations

Comment: Thanks! Made using the Google Docs Draw tool, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to also copy the objects in the list, and not only the references.

Answer (score 2):

You should also copy inner lists, so [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As `[:]` does only create a copy-slice of the list the slice is actually applied to, the reference to the objects stay the same.
Using deepcopy does recursively copy every item that can be pointed out.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name   = "unknown"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo: " + self.name

    def __copy__(self):
        f = Foo()
        f.name = self.name
        return f

    def __deepcopy__(self, d):
        return self.__copy__()

lst = [Foo()]
lst[0].name = "My first foo"

lst2 = lst[:]
lst2.append(Foo())
lst2[1].name = "My second foo"

print lst
print lst2
```

> ## output
>
> [Foo: My first foo]
>   [Foo: My first foo, Foo: My second foo]

```
lst2[0].name = "I changed the first foo"

print lst
print lst2
```

> ## output
>
> [Foo: I changed the first foo]
>   [Foo: I changed the first foo, Foo: My second foo]

```
from copy import deepcopy
lst[0].name = "My first foo"
lst3 = deepcopy(lst)
lst3[0].name = "I changed the first foo again !"

print lst
print lst3
```

> ## output
>
> [Foo: I changed the first foo]
>   [Foo: I changed the first foo again !]

Lists, tuples, etc do support `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` method.