# List copy not working?

Tags: python, list

I got something with Python that I can't understand. 
I have a list of lists, called data:

```
data = [[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
```

I want to create a copy of data, whose data would be reversed (1 becomes 99 and so on).

I then have the sorted_values and the reverse ones:

```
sorted_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 77, 78, 80, 82, 83, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99]
reverse_vals = [99, 98, 97, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 89, 88, 87, 83, 82, 80, 78, 77, 75, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 60, 58, 57, 56, 53, 52, 51, 50, 48, 47, 44, 43, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 23, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 11, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I create a copy of data:

```
rev_data = data[:]
```

Then, I change data while running through my list:

```
for index, item in enumerate(rev_data):
    for s_index, s_item in enumerate(item):
        rev_data[index][s_index] = reverse_val[sort_val.index(s_item)]
```

My problem is that whatever my method to create rev_data, data is also modified during the process!

I tried:

```
rev_data = list(data)
rev_data = data[:]

rev_data = []
rev_data.extend(data)
```

Each time, the final answer is correct, but data is also changed . . .

```
data = [[25], [4, 35], [83, 52, 18], [82, 64, 16, 91], [78, 95, 18, 52, 34], [80, 99, 77, 25, 97, 65], [14, 98, 23, 26, 93, 37, 32], [1, 34, 95, 71, 94, 87, 29, 9], [57, 57, 73, 43, 17, 58, 19, 29, 66], [57, 51, 27, 66, 52, 67, 63, 87, 6, 70], [44, 28, 53, 34, 75, 56, 10, 47, 3, 48, 88], [29, 89, 66, 71, 23, 26, 83, 20, 60, 31, 83, 41], [10, 28, 47, 62, 83, 88, 10, 56, 40, 50, 72, 70, 51], [37, 33, 95, 31, 11, 44, 32, 69, 26, 87, 30, 16, 58, 68], [95, 38, 2, 72, 77, 92, 29, 2, 26, 7, 62, 44, 39, 95, 77]]
```

Comment: there are several questions asking the same, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993531/copy-list-in-python and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350750/python-copy-list-issue

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`data[:]` creates a **shallow** copy of the list `data`.  Since this is a list of lists, and you also want to copy the inner lists, you need a **deep** copy instead:

```
rev_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
```

or

```
rev_data = [x[:] for x in data]
```

Comment: Man, so much answers in like 15 seconds ! o_O. I knew it had to be something with nested lists; whithout really getting the thing. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: It's worth noting that `deepcopy` comes with a pretty large performance hit (often an order of magnitude) compared to a list comprehension like this. So, if you can be sure that your lists will always be structured the same way, you'll probably be better off with the second option.

Answer (score 11):

use [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy nested mutable objects.

```
import copy
rev_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
.....................
```

That is:

```
>>> import copy
>>> data = [[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
>>> reverse_vals = [99, 98, 97, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 89, 88, 87, 83, 82, 80, 78, 77, 75, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 60, 58, 57, 56, 53, 52, 51, 50, 48, 47, 44, 43, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 23, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 11, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 77, 78, 80, 82, 83, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(rev_data):
...     for s_index, s_item in enumerate(item):
...         rev_data[index][s_index] = reverse_vals[sorted_vals.index(s_item)]
...         
>>> data
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
>>> rev_data
[[25], [4, 35], [83, 52, 18], [82, 64, 16, 91], [78, 95, 18, 52, 34], [80, 99, 77, 25, 97, 65], [14, 98, 23, 26, 93, 37, 32], [1, 34, 95, 71, 94, 87, 29, 9], [57, 57, 73, 43, 17, 58, 19, 29, 66], [57, 51, 27, 66, 52, 67, 63, 87, 6, 70], [44, 28, 53, 34, 75, 56, 10, 47, 3, 48, 88], [29, 89, 66, 71, 23, 26, 83, 20, 60, 31, 83, 41], [10, 28, 47, 62, 83, 88, 10, 56, 40, 50, 72, 70, 51], [37, 33, 95, 31, 11, 44, 32, 69, 26, 87, 30, 16, 58, 68], [95, 38, 2, 72, 77, 92, 29, 2, 26, 7, 62, 44, 39, 95, 77]]
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a list of nested lists, so you need to copy two levels deep.

```
data_copy = [inner_list[:] for inner_list in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

`reverse_data = reversed(data)`

`reverse_data` will be an iterator. You can either traverse it, or force it to a list with `list(reverse_data)`.

More on built-in functions: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed
 - Keep it under your pillow.

Edit: if you just want to have a list of values subtracted from 100:

```
from operator import sub
from functools import partial
subtract_map = partial(map, partial(sub,100)) # this is more convenient than a nested list comprehension
complements = [subtract_map(l) for l in data]
```

Comment: Downvoter: What's wrong? Don't believe that you can do it this easily?

Comment: Don't really know the reason either :s. Thanks for the tip anyway ;)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `reversed`

Comment: I am not sure what the OP wants, but his algorithm does not produce the reversed list.