# Duplication of one list into another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Its bit confusing that I haven't gone any assignment of list a[] with list coy,
still on output I get ,list a, same as ,list coy.I mean , how is that happening when I used coy=a[:].Thanks .

```
T=int(input())
for i in range(T):
    a=[]
    z=[]
    f=0
    count=0
    n,m=map(int,input().split())
    for i in range(n):
        a+=[list(map(int,input().split()))]
    coy=a[:]
    print(coy,'coy')#debug
    print(a,'a')#debug
    while(f==0):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                if i==0 and j==0:
                    coy[0][0]=max(a[i][j+1],a[i+1][j+1],a[i+1][j])
                elif i==0 and j==m-1:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j-1],a[i+1][j],a[i+1][j-1])
                elif i==n-1 and j==0:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j+1],a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j+1])
                elif i==n-1 and j==m-1:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i-1][j],a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j-1])
                elif j==0:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j+1],a[i-1][j],a[i+1][j],a[i-1][j+1],a[i+1][j+1],)
                elif j==m-1:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1],a[i+1][j],a[i+1][j-1])
                elif i==0:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j-1],a[i+1][j],a[i+1][j-1],a[i][j+1],a[i+1][j+1])
                elif i==n-1:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j-1],a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j+1],a[i][j+1])

                else:
                    coy[i][j]=max(a[i][j-1],a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1],a[i+1][j],a[i+1][j-1],a[i][j+1],a[i-1][j+1],a[i+1][j+1])
                    print('inside else','coy',coy,'a',a)#debug
        if(coy==a):
            print(coy,'coy')#debug
            print(a,'a')#debug

            count=0
            break

        for x in range(n):
            print('*')#debug
            z+=set(copy[x])
        print(z)
        if len(set(z))==1:
            f=1
        a=copy[:] 
        count+=1
        print('**********')#debug
    print(count)
```

I have used some print statement for viewing the flow, and the value of ,list a, gets changed during assignment of list coy indices, which ideally shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the identity of both lists "a" and "coy" using `id()` function. Both the lists might be same, because both the objects are referred to the same data. 
Check out all other possibilities of copying one list to other here.
[How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Both the  lists "a' and "coy" have different ids.

Comment: Look at the answers on Shallow copy and Deep copy in Python lists. [List Copy1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350750/python-copy-list-issue), [List Copy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993531/copy-list-in-python)